# clojure.async: "<! not in (go ...) block" error

Tags: clojure, core.async

When I evaluate the following core.async clojurescript code I get an error: "Uncaught Error: <! used not in (go ...) block"

```
(let [chans [(chan)]]
  (go
   (doall (for [c chans]
     (let [x (<! c)]
       x)))))
```

What am I doing wrong here? It definitely looks like the <! is in the go block.

Comment: This is a constraint of `go` blocks : `<!` won't work inside a `for` for instance. See [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040928/couldnt-use-for-loop-in-go-block-of-core-async) for a similar question.

Comment: @user229487 please mark the right post as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `go` blocks can't cross function boundaries I tend to fall back on loop/recur for a lot of these cases. the `(go (loop` pattern is so common that it has a short-hand form in core.async that is useful in cases like this:

```
user> (require '[clojure.core.async :as async])
user> (async/<!! (let [chans [(async/chan) (async/chan) (async/chan)]]
                   (doseq [c chans]
                     (async/go (async/>! c 42)))
                   (async/go-loop [[f & r] chans result []]
                     (if f
                       (recur r (conj result (async/<! f)))
                       result))))
[42 42 42]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use `alts!` from `Core.Async`?

This function lets you listen on multiple channels and know which channel you read from on each data.

For example:

```
(let [chans [(chan)]]
  (go
    (let [[data ch] (alts! chans)]
        data)))))
```

You can ask of the channel origin too:

```
...
(let [slow-chan (chan)
      fast-chan (chan)
      [data ch] (alts! [slow-chan fast-chan])]
    (when (= ch slow-chan)
       ...))
```

*From the Docs:*

> Completes at most one of several channel operations. Must be called
>   inside a (go ...) block. ports is a vector of channel endpoints,
>   which can be either a channel to take from or a vector of
>   [channel-to-put-to val-to-put], in any combination. Takes will be
>   made as if by !. Unless
>   the :priority option is true, if more than one port operation is
>   ready a non-deterministic choice will be made. If no operation is
>   ready and a :default value is supplied, [default-val :default] will
>   be returned, otherwise alts! will park until the first operation to
>   become ready completes. Returns [val port] of the completed
>   operation, where val is the value taken for takes, and a
>   boolean (true unless already closed, as per put!) for put

Doumentation [ref](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/alts!)